# Self hosted or cloud sql database?

Tags: database, server, cloud, hosting

I know this question was asked here before but why should I choose cloud sql?

I'm developing mobile game that will be relaying mostly on backend/database. I'm targeting 100.000 dau. I was looking at some options for hosting and cloud vps + cloud sql database are much more expensive that buying vps/dedicated machine.

I get that cloud take from me the administration/replication/backup part but the cost of it is insane.

For example, 4 cores 24gb ram and 100gb ssd https://www.ovh.pl/vps/vps-cloud-ram.xml cost ~45$.

For the same specs on google cloud I would need to pay more than 100$. We talking vps here which is cheaper than google cloud sql.

For example, I can have one backend server, one database server, one replication server, and one weak backup server for the price of 1 vps in google cloud.

Is this really worth it? 
Am I not seeing something?

I know that my time/team time cost a lot of money but we talking a small server here if we would want to scale this up to something bigger, buying a dedicated server is even a 10% of the google cloud vps price.

Comment: Hi, I am voting to closes this question since; many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.